# dcm4che2: DcmQR method get(results) does not work

Tags: java, dicom

I've found sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        DcmQR dcmqr = new DcmQR("server");

        dcmqr.setCalledAET("server", true);
        dcmqr.setRemoteHost("213.165.94.158");
        dcmqr.setRemotePort(104);

        dcmqr.setQueryLevel(DcmQR.QueryRetrieveLevel.PATIENT);
        dcmqr.configureTransferCapability(true);
        dcmqr.setCFind(true);
        dcmqr.setCGet(true);

        List<DicomObject> result=null;
        try {
            dcmqr.start();
            System.out.println("started");
            dcmqr.open();
            System.out.println("opened");
            result = dcmqr.query();
            dcmqr.get(result);
            System.out.println("List Size = " + result.size());
            dcmqr.stop();
            dcmqr.close();           
            }           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error: "+e);
        }

        System.out.println("done");
    }

}
```

Everything is fine until I call dcmqr.get(result);. After that I got exception:
error:

```
org.dcm4che2.net.NoPresentationContextException: 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.1.3/Patient Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - GET not supported by server
```

I use for testing public PACS server (http://www.dicomserver.co.uk/) which accepts C-FIND, C-GET, C-MOVE commands. I tried to do it using CONQUEST pacs - result is the same

Does enyone know what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your

```
dcmqr.configureTransferCapability(true);
```

after your

```
dcmqr.setCGet(true);
```

Otherwise, it will not configure the C-GET transfer capabilities properly.